# How to achieve dynamic fb actions?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

My site has a feed system and when user clicks on any one of those feed snippets (the object), I want the action to be publish in their Facebook news feed. So I'm really confused on how to go about it because as far as I'm aware this is how you post actions on Facebook's JavaScript SDK:

```
FB.api('/me/namespace:action?object=url','post')
```

How do you dynamically change the properties of the object? Are there parameters you can send? As far as I'm concerned, Facebook asks you to give pass a URL and it'll grab the `<meta>` information from that URL?

Am I supposed to perform a GET request with my own server and change the meta tags dynamically. This sounds like more work than it needs to be. For example, what if the feed includes a paragraph of text, it'll be impractical for me to post that as a get request and then `urldecode` the entire thing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I totally understand your question, but...

You can dynamically change the  tags for facebook og: properties, but you have to do it before the page loads (e.g. using PHP as opposed to javascript). After you send the post using the javascript SDK, facebook crawls the page and looks for the info in the og: meta tags.

Comment: if i use php, then i have to use a get request. what if my og:description is really long (like a paragraph). that seems like a rather roundabout way of doing things, using both php and js. i wish i can just pass the title, description, etc. as parameters...sigh

Comment: yeah, really my only experience with open graph and dynamic og: properties has been loading them in from a database. If it help, I learned that when you submit that link via the javascript SDK, facebook then scrapes that particular link for the og: data and then uses that info when posting to a person's timeline / whatever.